# One instrumentation test runner needs to call another test runner and wait until the second test runner is done executing its testcase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-instrumentation

I have a UI android app which can be used to invoke different testcases executing one after the other thru UI. I am trying to add instrumentation test runner for the same app. But this newly added testrunner dies after execution of first testcase. My requirement is pretty similar to [How to elegantly wait for test case to finish after call to startInstrumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229606/how-to-elegantly-wait-for-test-case-to-finish-after-call-to-startinstrumentation) . This is from six years ago. But I see no responses to that thread. Can someone revisit this and let me know if there is something that can be done ?

startInstrumentation(name, null, bundleParams);